Draw a square with asterisks '*'
I have a requirement to draw n number of squares with side length m in the following format:
Example: m=5;n=2;
Expected output
 * * * * * * * *
 *     *       *
 *     *       *
 *     *       *
 * * * * * * * *

This is the method I wrote, but it isn't working as it should be:
Console.Write("Enter the value of m (side length): ");
int m = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Enter the value of n (number of squares): ");
int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < m; k++)
        {
            Console.Write("* ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}


What is the current output and what is the expected output?

If you expected to draw 2 squares with a height of 5 stars, the expected output should also be squares, no? Currently your expected output shows 1 rectangle and 1 square not 2 squares. I think the left side is missing 1 more * in it's width.

Before start coding, start shape analysis, what is the dimension (width and height) of the output Shape as function of (m, n)
the height is easy to determine, is just m so lets determine the width of the shape
the following pattern is repeated n times
****
   *
   *
   *
****

every single pattern width is (m-1) so the result width is (m-1)n and we need to add this shape to the column of asterisks at the beginning to make it complete square
*
*
*
*
*

so the total width is (m-1)n+1 simplify it mn-n+1
your shape is consisted of asterisks * and spaces   and we need to know where to put asterisk and where to put space
*********



*********

the first horizontal line and last one, all of them are asterisks
the column is repeated every  (m-1) time, we can use modulus operator to say it repeated
the rest of the shape should be space
Console.Write("Enter the value of m (side length): ");
int m = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Enter the value of n (number of squares): ");
int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

var width = m * n - n + 1;
var height = m;
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        if (y == 0 || y == height - 1)
            Console.Write('*');
        else if(x%(m-1)==0)
            Console.Write('*');
        else
            Console.Write(' ');
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}


Thank you! I've just added Console.Write(' ') in the second "for", so it looks better.
